# Is there a way to support Tailwind @apply in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tailwind-css

I have a C#/Blazor project where i use tailwindcss for the user interface. Visual Studio highlights the @apply directives in the .css files from tailwind as unkown @-blocks. Are there any ways to teach Visual Studio about them, disable this warning or replace @apply by some known directives?

Example:

```
table {
    @apply table-fixed inline-block border-collapse overflow-hidden border border-gray-dark rounded;
}
```

For the *@tailwindcss* directives i used the replacements *@import 'tailwindcss/base';* and so on.

Comment: In Razor (and I assume, also Blazor), use `@@` to escape at-symbols.

Comment: I am talking about css (.css files) - it's purely a Visual Studio related thing, has nothing to do with the framework

Answer (score 0):

Getting those warnings are completely fine, if you still want to remove it than install [PostCSS Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss) plugin for VSCode

Comment: I know that the warnings are fine, but they are shown in the warnings list - where i don't want them as the @applys are correct. Thanks for the suggestion, but i am working with VisualStudio 2022 (not VSCode), where i could not find any similar extensions